# UI Architecture

Tags: architecture, ui, typescript

I'm confused in architecture solution for boolean expression tree.
Business logic has algo to parse config and make a tree from such expressions.

```
(a && b || c) && d || (e && f)
```

So in UI  a,b,c,d,e is cells, they can be swapped (via dnd).
() - is layer(s), which can be or can not be in expression.
a && b && c - has no bg layers.
a && (b && c) - has layer for b and c cells.
Layers can be resized/removed/added etc. But I know how and what to 
do for validation.
&& and || are operators. Operator can be changed, so UI operator is having a type (AND || OR).

If use MVP and html for UI. It can be something like this.

```
class QueryView {

  public el = document.createElementNS(XMLNS, "g");

  constructor(private _presenter: Container) {
    this._presenter.setView(this);
  }

  public init(cells: Cell[], operators: Operator[], layers: Layer[]) {

  }

  private initCells() {
    // initial rendering of cells ?
  } 

  private initOperators() {
    // initial rendering of operators ?
  }

  private initLayers() {
    // initial rendering of layers ?
  }

  private listen() {
    // listen for clicks drops resizes etc. and call presenter methods
  }
}
```

But in such case Operator View can directly change Operator type in Operator model. OperatorView.click = OperatorPresenter.toogleType().

I'm also confused cuz QueryView has data collections, and items from this collections can have own views which are subviews for QueryView.

Result(current state) from this QueryView will be passed to main business logic, where QueryTree will be created/updated. So please think about this boolean expression builder as about separate part. Cuz main logic starts from parsing expressions, and expression can be just a string like in examples.

EDIT: As I understand everything must(may) be nested. If query model has tree it will also have models for operators, conditions, filters.
So queryPresenter will get data from model then it will create needed presenters for operators (maybe for layers) and cells(filters). And each presenter will have own view. 
For me such triads logic is new so anyway any answer will be helpfull.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question what's going on here.  You've stated some, but not all, of your technologies, and what you have provided doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Sounds to me you are conflating the presentation logic (these values formatted and displayed in these locations) and your business logic (a set of cells with some having customised logic on how to determine their real value).

Answer (score -1):

In general, use a data structure such as streams to model boolean logic. For example:

```
function checkIfOdd(x) {
  if (x % 2 == 0) {
    // even number
    return false;
  } else {
    // odd number
    return true;
  }
}
var numbers = Stream.range(10, 15);
numbers.print(); // => 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
var onlyOdds = numbers.filter(checkIfOdd);
onlyOdds.print(); // => 11, 13, 15
```

**References**

- [GitHub - dionyziz/stream.js: A tiny stand-alone Javascript library for streams](https://github.com/dionyziz/stream.js)
- [More Goodies - stream.js](https://dionyziz.github.io/stream.js-website/getting_started/More_Goodies.html)